# Confidence Limit for Inference on Ratios

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, proportion, poisson-regression, ratio

I need to know how to construct a confidence interval on a Ratio which is the number of Incidents per Vehicle, calculated as shown for a schematic example in the image below.[image: example calculation]

As shown in the image, I have a control group and then a treatment group. For each there is an incident rate calculated at the bottom. The observation periods for the two groups are identical.

I have a cost per incident, and want to assess the savings that can be achieved for different vehicle volumes if the treatment is applied.

Note that the number of observations in the two groups are not the same. Also note (a) in reality I have many more observations (more than 150 for each group); (b) there are a lot of zeros in the incident column.

My question is - what approach/formula should I use to calculate a Confidence Interval on each of the two ratios? I am aware that if the outcome was simply a number of Yes/No values, then I could use the formula for a confidence limit on a binomial parameter, or something like the Agresti-Coull confidence interval. But I am not sure if these formulas apply to a ratio calculated in the manner shown above?

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why not model the count of incidents with the number of Vehicles as an offset and use a Poisson model?  You can very easily obtain confidence intervals for the expected number of incidents from this model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy to compute compute the CIs for these.  As you've said you can just pool the incidents and vehicles and then use any number of binomial CI methods.

However, there may be some benefit to modelling the data as is.  You've got a lot of zeros, which means it might be beneficial to model the data as coming from a zero inflated process.  In what follows, I will model the data as coming from a poisson, which can easily be extended to the zero inflated poisson case should you choose to pursue this.

Combine the data into a single dataset and indicate if the data come from treat or control.

```
library(tidyverse)


control<-tibble(
  vehicles=c(99,94,14,67,47,90,83,88,23,69),
  incidents=c(0,4,0,1,0,0,0,3,2,0),
  group = '_control'
)

treat<-tibble(
  vehicles = c(76,18,26,44,67,32,93),
  incidents = c(0,2,0,1,0,0,0),
  group = '_treat'
)
```

Then, model the data.  I'm using a poisson regression, but there are a lot of zeros so this might not be the best model.  Include an offset for the number of vehicles.

```
model_data = bind_rows(control, treat)


model = glm(incidents ~ group, offset = log(vehicles), data = model_data, family =poisson)
```

Use your model to predict on new data.

```
pred_data = tibble(group = c('_treat', '_control'), vehicles = 100)
pred = predict(model, newdata = pred_data, se.fit = T) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Then, use `exp(fit + 2*se)`  to get confidence intervals for each group (test/control).

```
pred %>% 
  bind_cols(pred_data) %>% 
  transmute(group = group,
            ratio = exp(fit), 
            ratio_upper = exp(fit + 2*se.fit),
            ratio_lower = exp(fit - 2*se.fit))


   group ratio ratio_upper ratio_lower
1   _treat  0.84        2.67        0.27
2 _control  1.48        2.79        0.79
```

So our estimates for the number of incidences for the treatment group is 0.84 incidents per 100 vehicles, with a confidence interval of 0.27 to 2.67.  Same can be said for control.

You will get different answers depending on what your likelihood is.  I would need to know more about what is being modeled before recommending anything further.

Comment: Many thanks Demetri for your answer which is very clear and comprehensive. The R code also will be very helpful. Just to be sure, referring to your first paragraph: you are sure that using binomial CI estimates on the pooled ratios is valid? To give you more context - I am trying to assess the benefits of fixing defects on roads. I actually have different blocks of data to represent different conditions (e.g. tight curves, low traffic, then no curves, high traffic etc), and for each of these situations, I have data such as I have shown.

Comment: @Fritz45 WHat is your goal with the different blocks?  Do you want to assess how the conditions may affect the treatment effect?

Comment: We know from historical data that the treatment effect is greater in some blocks than others, and traffic volumes vary over the blocks, hence benefits of treatments also. So the plan is to calculate a treatment benefit (incident reduction) for each block. This gives a more precise outcome than doing a single combined estimate across all blocks. I realize that a model in which the block characteristics are included may be a more sophisticated approach, but there is a lot of variability and the Poisson model I tried before performed rather poorly. So I am pursuing a more transparent approach.

Comment: Hmm.  I say just pool and present a confidence interval.  It seems you already know that there is heterogeneity of the effect by block.  If you've already tried to control for that and run into troubles, just present the pooled estimate and note that it may be a conservative estimate of the treatment effect.  I'd have to be more familiar with your data to be more helpful.